# A faster way to execute javascript code within Java(sdk1.4)

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, rhino

Currently, I am using Rhino engine to execute some big blocks of javascript code on the server side. However, sometimes, it takes so long(more than 10 minutes) and eat up all CPU usage (at least on my local development env, it is doing this right now).

So I am wondering that what I can do to improve the current system or I can try a new one there.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

PLUS:
It throws the exception while the code is too big:
java.lang.Exception: No Context associated with current Thread

Comment: Before looking at what the *platform* can do for you, you need to figure out what's wrong with your software. Find out where it's spending it's time, and you'll probably find some bad code using an inefficient algorithm. No better interpreter is going to help that.

Comment: @Pointy  I wish I could. However, the javascript is not under my control...:(

Comment: Well I can tell you right now with near-100% certainty that no improvement to your Javascript interpreter is going to make a significant difference, even if the code is 100% CPU-bound. (That's of course something you should verify before even bothering to experiment, I suggest. If it's waiting on external activity like a database, then clearly it's not a script performance issue at all.)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the script before running it and cache the compiled version
see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/CompiledScript.html

(edit: ops... i don't know if that would work on sdk 1.4)

Comment: I seriously doubt that'll make much difference.

Comment: Thank you. The fact is that the javascript code are dynamically generated from database, and not guaranteed to be the same every time. Besides, I donot want to sacrifice the compiling time either. Sorry that I didnot give the assumption at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

We first have to know how big are the Javascript blocks that you are executing? 10 lines? 50 lines? 1000 lines?

If its getting 50+, then perhaps compiling would help. Since you are using 1.4, you must be using the official Rhino distribution and not javax.script. In that case just use the [rhino compiler](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/jsc.html).

First though, have you profiled your program? Perhaps its something else thats causing the issue.

Are you sure your algorithm is as efficient as possible?

Please consider these before blaming Rhino

Answer (score 0):

You generate the whole javascript code dynamically from database? maybe you could consider writing a fix piece of code, and filling data into the code with functions like:

```
        ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "out", out);
        ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "script", script);
```

then you can compile it, and store the 'scope' somewhere and reuse it.

Use the latest release of Rhino, which always has a 'jdk1.4' jar in the release, use it, maybe it'll help.